# Combining purchases by transaction sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a problem and I am stuck in generating a decision table.

Suppose you are given a table of people's purchase habit, what I am trying to generate is the unique combination of product pairs that were purchsed together, consider this toy example to illustrate the problem.

```
+-------+-----------------+---------+
| buyer | transaction seq | product |
+-------+-----------------+---------+
| 1     | 1               | milk    |
| 1     | 1               | butter  |
| 1     | 2               | milk    |
| 2     | 1               | butter  |
| 2     | 2               | milk    |
| 3     | 1               | butter  |
| 3     | 2               | spoon   |
+-------+-----------------+---------+
```

you have the buyer ID, transaction sequence for that particular buyer and what product he purchased. So the first row tells us buyer 1 purchased milk & butter in his first transaction and again milk in his second transaction.

therefore, for buyer 1, the total possible product combinations are-

```
1. milk (tr1) & milk (tr2)
2. butter (tr1) & milk (tr2)
```

So, you can think of it as the cartesian join of all possible combinations.

Similarly, for buyer 2, the only possible combination is (butter and milk)

For buyer 3, it is (butter & spoon).

At the end of the day, I want to count the number of such unique combinations. In this case, it will be,

```
 
+---------------+-------+
| combination   | count |
+---------------+-------+
| milk; milk    | 1     |
| butter; milk  | 2     |
| butter; spoon | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
```

Remember that we need to make sure that the order is not changed, so (butter + milk) is not the same as (milk + butter), since transaction order matters and so they should be counted separately as individual groups.

How can I do this in MySQL, if I were given the table above? any ideas?

Comment: `since transaction order matters` ... if this is really the case, then you absolutely need to add a timestamp column of some sort which keeps track of when purchase actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but that is what the transaction id tells you. All I care about the transactions for a particular buyer and I don't care if buyer A's first transaction is before buyer B's first transaction. If that makes thing clear. This is because I am treating all first transactions as a group, irrespective of when EXACTLY they were made. Let me know if you re clear here

Comment: Why should we have milk; milk instead of milk ? No one bought milk 2 times.

Comment: I have made a query but the result is not like you, I used group_concat()

Comment: Check row 1 and row 3 --> buyer 1 bought milk in his 1st transactions and then AGAIN milk in his second transaction. Hence `milk; milk` . If you see the final table it is a summarization of documenting people's buying habits. The goal is to answer question like - if someone buys milk in his first purchase, what is he most likely to buy in his second purchase? Does that make sense ??

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta if you can share your code, it will be helpful; might give us some ideas here. Thanks

Comment: No, my code is wrong. Your problem is too complex for me :( I'll wait until someone give the solution

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway, @ArnaudPeralta . This is an interesting problem though and I believe one needs to be a little bit seasoned in SQL to answer this. Hence reaching out to you all. I appreciate you spent time trying to solve it. :)

Comment: Presumably, a unique key can be formed on (buyer,transaction seq,product )?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a self join.

```
select p.product as first_product,
       p2.product as second_product,
       count(distinct p.buyer) as num_buyers,
       count(*) as num_purchases
from purchases p join
     purchases p2
     on p2.buyer = p.buyer and
        p2.seq > p.seq
group by p.product, p2.product
order by num_buyers desc;
```

I don't see a need to concatenate the products into a single column.

Your question is vague on a few details:

- Are you counting buyers or purchases?
- Does the "next" purchase have to be on the the next transaction or on any following transaction?
- Can the same product be purchased multiple times?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :) I am counting purchases, but it is nice to have the buyer count as well. Yes the same product can be purchased multiple time but we can treat them as one (means I am not interested if someone buys two butters, I am just simply going to take it as butter was purchased on transaction 1).